# Ошибка MVC1005 Using 'UseMvc' to configure MVC is not supported while using Endpoint Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

У меня есть проект Asp.Net core 2.2

Недавно я поменял версию с 2.2 на 3.0 Preview 8. После этого изменения я увидел следующее предупреждение:

```
using 'UseMvc' to configure MVC is not supported while using Endpoint Routing. To continue using 'UseMvc', please set 'MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false' inside 'ConfigureServices'.
```

Я понимаю, что можно поставить настройку EnableEndpointRouting в false и решить проблему, но хочу понять какой подходщий путь следует использовать и почему Endpoint Routing не требует функций `UseMvc()`.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Using 'UseMvc' to configure MVC is not supported while using Endpoint Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57684093/5752652) от участника  [@Mehrdad Babaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2989995/mehrdad-babaki).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57684093/

Answer (score 4):

Нашёл решение в официальной документации "[Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)":

Есть три подхода:

> 1. Замена UseMvc или UseSignalR на UseEndpoints

В моём случае результат будет выглядеть так:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Old Way
        services.AddMvc();
        // New Ways
        //services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        });
        
    }
}
```

> Или
> 2. Использование AddControllers() и UseEndpoints()

```
public class Startup
{
    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
        
    }
}
```

> Или
> 3. Запрет endpoint Routing. То как предлагалось в сообщении с exception'ом и как упомянуто в следующем разделе документации: [use mvcwithout endpoint routing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-mvc-without-endpoint-routing)

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
//OR
services.AddControllers(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/58267385/5752652 от участника  [@Sergii Zhuravskyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7850307/sergii-zhuravskyi).</sub>